# SSH tunnel between a client and a server

Tags: android, ssh

I have a client-server application for Android.
For security reasons it was decided to raise between client and server SSH tunnel to protect the information transmitted.
For SSH I used a application ConnectBot.
Is there any sense in raising SSH to sew in the app itself?

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Comment: What value would any sort of proxy add?

Comment: gview, as a proxy I used the gateway of ssh-server

Comment: Although proxies really don't need, because I need a connection only to the server